# moving views between containers

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

what is the best practice to move views between different containers, mvvm/reactiveui wise?

Platform: WPF (.Net 4.5)

I'm having two different containers, say listbox on the left, grid on the right and I want to animate moving an element of the listbox to a grid's cell. 
The moved element contains other ui elements, so when translating and zooming the element these controls have to resize/move accordingly.

In a dummy application with just views and no viewmodels it is no problem: animate the element, detach it from the old parent, add it as a child for the new parent at the end of the animation...

How is this done in a conceptually clean way?

edit: this is the kind of animation I want to implement: 
[image: move]

Comment: Hey Geoffrey, I'll join you as soon as I find the time later on, thanks! (platform see edit)

Comment: It is customary to perform these kinds of cross control animations using an Adorner. See the [Adorners Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/controls/adorners-overview) page on the microsoft.com website.

Comment: Well, I want to achieve effects like the ones defined in material design (e.g. https://material.io/guidelines/motion/choreography.html#choreography-continuity ) . So I really want to animate the whole child (or at least parts of it) moving from one container to the other. But thanks, I'll check if I can achieve that with the help of Adorners.